Wireguard - Handshake for peer did not complete after 5 seconds
I have issues with stability of my wireguard connection. I have set up 3 VPN networks (explained below) but let's focus on first one (wg0). Everything works but after a while connection fails, client tries to initialize new handshake, server responds but the response never gets to the client for some reason. Reseting the connection resolves the issue unitil it breaks again.
I tried:
1. Setting policy ACCEPT on chain input to check if firewall is a issue on server.
2. Setting policy ACCEPT on chain forward to check if firewall is a issue on server.
3. Disabling windows firewall.
4. Lowering MTU on both client and server.
5. Setting PersistentKeepalive on both client and server.
6. Settiing very low PersistentKeepalive on client.

Context:
1. Client is a windows PC behind NAT in home network.
2. Server is a linux VPS with public IP on hetzner hosting.

Wireshark caputure (images):
server (eth0)
client
1. Successfull handshake, then few times client manages to make few handshakes again. 
2. Issue with connection.
3. I disconect client.
4. I ping client from server, server tries to initialize handshakes,
they get throught to client but client is disabled thus they do not succeed.
This proves no network or firewall block on client side.

Client wireguard logs:
Handshake for peer 1 (REDACTED:10000) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (REDACTED:10000)
Handshake for peer 1 (REDACTED:10000) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 3)
Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (REDACTED:10000)
Handshake for peer 1 (REDACTED:10000) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 4)

Client config:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = REDACTED
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8
MTU = 1280

[Peer]
PublicKey = REDACTED
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/16
Endpoint = REDACTED:10000
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Server config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24

ListenPort = 10000
PrivateKey = REDACTED
MTU = 1280

#pc
[Peer]
PublicKey = REDACTED
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

Iptables rules (script):
iptables -F -t filter
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -X -t filter
iptables -X -t nat
iptables -X -t mangle

#Set policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#Group rules into chains
iptables -N _INPUT
iptables -N _OUTPUT
iptables -N _FORWARD
iptables -N _POSTROUTING -t nat

#Append chains
iptables -A INPUT -j _INPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j _OUTPUT
iptables -A FORWARD -j _FORWARD
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j _POSTROUTING

#Allow related and established connections
iptables -A _INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A _FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow loopback
iptables -A _INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#Wireguard [wg0] (10.0.0.0/24) -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Allow all trafic from devices in this network
iptables -I _FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I _INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

#Open port for this network network
iptables -A _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

#Allow internet access
iptables -A _POSTROUTING -t nat -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#Wireguard [wg1] (10.0.1.0/24) -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Allow traffic to other devices in wg1 and wg2
iptables -A _FORWARD -i wg1 -o wg1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A _FORWARD -i wg1 -o wg2 -j ACCEPT

#Open port for this network
iptables -A _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10010 -j ACCEPT

#Allow internet access
iptables -A _FORWARD -i wg1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A _POSTROUTING -t nat -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#Wireguard [wg2] (10.0.2.0/24) -------------------------------------------------------------------------

iptables -A _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10020 -j ACCEPT

#Logging -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Log new accepted on wireguard ports
#iptables -I _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix "WIREGUARD_NEW_WG0: " --log-level 7
#iptables -I _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10010 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix "WIREGUARD_NEW_WG1: " --log-level 7
#iptables -I _INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 10020 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix "WIREGUARD_NEW_WG2: " --log-level 7

#Log dropped on _FORWARD
iptables -A _FORWARD -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES_FRWD_DROP: " --log-level 7

Networks explained:
[wg0] - Highest level of trust
Subnet for this network: 10.0.0.0/24
Interface address: 10.0.0.1
Client addresses: from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.254
Listen port: 10000
Devices in this network can access:

Internet
Devices in network wg0
Devices in network wg1
Devices in network wg2

[wg1] - Limited/Conditional trust
Subnet for this network: 10.0.1.0/24
Interface address: 10.0.1.1
Client addresses: from 10.0.1.2 to 10.0.1.254
Listen port: 10010
Devices in this network can access:

Internet
Devices in network wg1
Devices in network wg2

[wg2] - No trust
Subnet for this network: 10.0.2.0/24
Interface address: 10.0.2.1
Client addresses: from 10.0.2.2 to 10.2.0.254
Listen port: 10020
Devices in this network can access:

Nothing


Disabling windows firewall. did you try disabling the linux firewall

Yes, take a look at two first points in "I tried" section.

Does the home IP change or are you behind CGNAT?

@JuliePelletier I have checked right now, my router is IPv6 only (cannot change) but I have public IPv4 IP. Also my public IPv6 does not match IPv6 my router was given. So I guess yes, am behind CGNAT.

my public IPv6 does not match IPv6 my router was given. So I guess yes, am behind CGNAT ... except that CGNAT is an IPv4 thing, so

take a look at two first points in "I tried" neither of which DISABLE the fierwall, but I guess that's close enough

From your packet captures, it looks like one of two things:

Rate limiting on the path from your WireGuard server to the client. If you leave the client on and the handshakes eventually start succeeding again after several minutes of trying, then this is probably the case (packets are dropped until their rate over the past X seconds falls back down below Y packets or Z bytes).

Broken UDP flow tracking on the path from your WireGuard server to the client. If the only way to fix the connection is to turn your client off for a minute or two, then this is probably the case (the flow is getting tagged as invalid, and packets are dropped until none are seen for long enough for the flow to time out).


Unfortunately, either way, there's not much you can do about it unless it's one of your own routers that's causing the problem. On your own routers, try turning off any rate limiting or connection/flow tracking on them (at least for traffic to & from your WireGuard server).
